# Azure device twin add new reported property

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am following the azure device twin tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-node-twin-how-to-configure

I can make this work to update an existing reported property.  What I am not sure about is how can I add a new reported property.

Specifically the code looks snippet looks like:

```
 var currentTelemetryConfig = twin.properties.reported.telemetryConfig;
 currentTelemetryConfig.pendingConfig = 
 twin.properties.desired.telemetryConfig;
 currentTelemetryConfig.status = "Pending";

 telemetryConfig: currentTelemetryConfig

 var patch = {
    telemetryConfig: currentTelemetryConfig
 };

 twin.properties.reported.update(patch, function(err) {  
  if (err) {
         console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('success');
 }
}
```

I can easily understand how this works for the existing property update (in this case the telemetryConfig) but what would it look like if the change I was trying to make was to a entirely new property?

How would it work if I decide at some point the I want a a new desired property called "favourite_colour" : "blue"?

In the azure backend I can add this but how do I dynamically build the var patch variable?

I tried this but it returned an error:

```
twin.properties.reported.update(twin.properties.desired, function(err) {
     if (err) {
         console.log('Could not report properties');
     } else {
         console.log('Success');
     }
 });
```

This is what my twin looks like:

```
"properties": {
"desired": {
  "active": true,
  "pws": "xyz",
  "$metadata": {
    "$lastUpdated": "2018-03-27T18:21:57.010036Z",
    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 5,
    "active": {
      "$lastUpdated": "2018-03-27T18:21:57.010036Z",
      "$lastUpdatedVersion": 5
    },
    "pws": {
      "$lastUpdated": "2018-03-27T18:21:57.010036Z",
      "$lastUpdatedVersion": 5
    }
  },
  "$version": 5
},
"reported": {
  "telemetryConfig": 6,
  "$metadata": {
    "$lastUpdated": "2018-03-27T18:56:05.2445399Z",
    "telemetryConfig": {
      "$lastUpdated": "2018-03-27T18:56:05.2445399Z"
    }
  },
  "$version": 5
}
```

}
}

Comment: can you also provide what your device twin looks like? Which level is your new property? And what is the code that corresponds to your new property?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to:

> Add new reported property on device side (favourite_colour)

I first recommend you to read this [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device_twin.js) in GitHub.
Main this sample shows different way to listen for updates in twin on different level. The top most, where any update in device twin will trigger an event; or specific property (favourite_color).

I've edited the sample from the Microsoft document you provided to work with **favorite_color**.

```
'use strict';
var Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;

var connectionString = '{iot hub connection string}';
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Protocol);

var initConfigChange = function(twin, patch) {
    twin.properties.reported.update(patch, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Could not report properties');
        } else {
            console.log('Reported pending config change: ' + JSON.stringify(patch));
            setTimeout(function() {completeConfigChange(twin, patch);}, 30000);
        }
    });
}

var completeConfigChange =  function(twin, patch) {
    if (patch.telemetryConfig) {
        // Same as Sample
    } else if (patch.favourite_colour) {
        var currentfavourite_colour = twin.properties.reported.favourite_colour;
        currentfavourite_colour.color = currentfavourite_colour.pendingConfig.color;
        currentfavourite_colour.status = "Success";
        delete currentfavourite_colour.pendingConfig;

        var patch = {
            favourite_colour: currentfavourite_colour
        };    
        patch.favourite_colour.pendingConfig = null;
    }

    twin.properties.reported.update(patch, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error reporting properties: ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log('Reported completed config change: ' + JSON.stringify(patch));
        }
    });
};

client.open(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('could not open IotHub client');
    } else {
        client.getTwin(function(err, twin) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('could not get twin');
            } else {
                console.log('retrieved device twin');
                twin.properties.reported.favourite_colour = {
                    color: "green"
                }

                twin.on('properties.desired', function(desiredChange) {
                    console.log("received change: "+JSON.stringify(desiredChange));
                    if (desiredChange.telemetryConfig) {
                        // Same as sample
                    } else if (desiredChange.favourite_colour) {

                        var currentfavourite_colour = twin.properties.reported.favourite_colour;
                        currentfavourite_colour.pendingConfig = twin.properties.desired.favourite_colour;
                        currentfavourite_colour.status = "Pending Color";

                        var patch = {
                            favourite_colour: currentfavourite_colour
                        };
                        initConfigChange(twin, patch);
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What I did was use a *if else* statement to check the reported property; as I mentioned there are other ways to do this, check the GitHub code I provided earlier. Once I have the matched reported property I can update the in the same way as the existing sample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The problem with this answer is the client side code needs to be coded to accept the favorite color property.  If this code was deployed to remote iot device and I added property to my device twin that was "favorite_ice_cream".  How would it it handle it.  That is my real question.

Comment: hmm so let me understand this. You are saying the device is already built, deployed, running. And from the cloud you added a new twin property that it doesn't recognize, how would you handle it? Well, it won't handle/read that particular property, act as if it doesn't exist. I think you have to code the logic for each twin property that you want to give action to.

Comment: You are right - I thought a lot more about this and the use case does not make any sense.  Thank you for you time.